# Interface contravariance when used as type constraint

Tags: c#

I have an interface and a derived type from it

```
public interface ITransformationRule<in TSource, in TResult, in TContext> {...}
public class MyRule : ITransformationRule<object, object, object> {...}
```

Then I have a rule engine which has the following method

```
public class RuleEngine<TContext>
{
    public void Register<TRule, TSource, TResult>() // I would like to keep it just Register<TRule> but compiler would not let me
        where TRule : ITransformationRule<TSource, TResult, TContext> {...}
}
```

And now I want to register that rule somewhere with:

```
var engine = new RuleEngine<object>();
engine.Register<MyRule>(); // this fails to compile
engine.Register<MyRule, object, object>(); // this is OK
```

The question is how can I call Register method with just one type parameter (MyRule) and would not have to specify TSource and TResult? I know that I can just drop the constraint from it, but I intend to keep it.

Comment: What if you do `public void Register<TRule>() where TRule : ITransformationRule<object, object, TContext> `?

Comment: i have tried this approach, but did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public interface ITransformationRule<in TSource, in TResult, in TContext> {}
public class MyRule : ITransformationRule<object, object, object> {}

public class RuleEngine<TContext, TSource, TResult>
{
    public void Register<TRule>() // I would like to keep it just Register<TRule> but compiler would not let me
        where TRule : ITransformationRule<TSource, TResult, TContext>
    {

    }

}

var engine = new RuleEngine<object, object, object>();
engine.Register<MyRule>();
```

**EDIT:** Using Jakub Dąbek approach

```
public interface ITransformationRule<in TSource, in TResult, in TContext> { }
public class MyRule : ITransformationRule<object, object, object> { }

public class RuleEngine<TContext>
{
    public void Register<TRule>() // I would like to keep it just Register<TRule> but compiler would not let me
        where TRule : ITransformationRule<object, object, TContext>
    {

    }

}

var engine = new RuleEngine<object>();
engine.Register<MyRule>();
```

Comment: i have reviewed the design of my solution and decided this would be the best option in my case. Thank you.

Although it still interests me if it could be done in the original way (without adding type modifiers to RuleEngine).

Comment: the Jakub Dąbek approach is the other option. I will update my example with it.

Comment: But i think is more restrictive. Depended on your use case, can or not be a solution.